# How to get Value from XML Document (VB.NET)

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

> ```
> <Send>
>    <Title>myTitle</Title>
>    <User>username</User>
>    <Transaction>106100</Transaction>
>    <Items>
>      <Item ID="12345" Name="myName" Birthday="myBirthday" Address="myAddress"/>
>    </Items>
> </Send>
> ```

If I have this kind of XML document. How can I get the value of ID (which is **`12345`** )inside the `<Item ... />` tag? Using VB.Net?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I'm looking for...

where `itemID` contains the `12345`

```
_strMessage = 
        <Send>
           <Title>myTitle</Title>
           <User>username</User>
           <Transaction>106100</Transaction>
           <Items>
             <Item ID="12345" Name="myName" Birthday="myBirthday" Address="myAddress"/>
           </Items>
        </Send>

    Dim xMessage As XElement = XElement.Parse(_strMessage) 
    Dim items = xMessage.Descendants("Items").FirstOrDefault 
    Dim itemID As String = String.Empty 
    itemID = items.Descendants("Item").FirstOrDefault.Attribute("itemID").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq

Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test2.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim items As List(Of Item) = doc.Descendants("Item").Select(Function(x) New Item() With { _
                                                                        .id = x.Attribute("ID").Value, _
                                                                        .name = x.Attribute("Name").Value, _
                                                                        .birthday = x.Attribute("Birthday").Value, _
                                                                        .address = x.Attribute("Address").Value _
                                                                    }).ToList()

    End Sub

End Module
Public Class Item
    Public id As String
    Public name As String
    Public birthday As String
    Public address As String

End Class
```